# How to SELECT data from two tables which only first row of second table is selected for one row of first table

Tags: php, mysql, select, row

Table 1 contains fields: tab1_id name, description

Table 2 contains fields: tab2_id,id,choice.

By using the following query

```
  SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
  INNER JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t1.tab1_id=t2.id
```

it returned several rows of table2 for each t1.tab1_id.

What I want is to get only first row of table2 for each ta.tab1_id.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a GROUP BY, just make sure to include every column in your GROUP BY that you want to use in your SELECT clause, i.e.:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.tab1_id=t2.id
GROUP BY t1.tab1_id
;
```

Comment: Your answer is very simple and also my need. Thanks Ruben.